# How to increase execution time of shell commands?

Tags: php, python, cakephp, nginx

I am using `exec()` to run python script from `cakephp`, upto 30 seconds it is working fine after that php is aborting but still in background python is running to complete the process.

I am using ajax post method and running python and waiting for response. In this workflow if execution of python is crossing 30 seconds the php is not waiting for the response. I am using `nginx` server. I tried to modify `php.ini` file to increase `max_execution_time=600`. But still the issue remains same.

Comment: you may try this ini_set('max_execution_time', '600'); for exec().

Comment: http://php.net/set_time_limit - That has more information on long running processes

Comment: Please edit your original (not updated) question, asking the same question again is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_time_limit()` for example:

```
<?php
  set_time_limit(40);//set script's execution time limit to 40 seconds
```

in large backstage task, I usually apply `set_time_limit(0);` which means no time limit is imposed.